# How to copy Vietnamese text from a PDF and paste it into an InDesign document, keeping the special characters?

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, character, document-setup

I'm trying to copy text from a Vietnamese language PDF into inDesign and many characters are incorrectly copied.

For example, this is the correct text:

```
PHỞ ÐẶC BIỆT
```

This is what it's pasted as:

```
PHª ñ¥C BIOET
```

**What's the most effective and reliable method for copying and placing this text into InDesign?**

I realize that I may not be able to do this completely automatically. Anything that would speed up the process of copying large amounts of text with special characters would help.

Comment: Have you tried `File > Save As > More Options > Text (plain)` within Acrobat? I can't say it'll be better.. but I'd at least try it.

Comment: Yes, saving it as text doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

You need to:

- start w/ a .pdf which has the characters encoded using Unicode (check document properties)
- have the font in InDesign set to one which has those characters at the same Unicode slots

Then it'll ``just work''.

Answer (score 0):

In Adobe Acrobat:

1. Click Edit in top menu
2. Select Edit Text & Images
3. Copy and paste from there
4. Profit